# How to send json instead of params in spring test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, mockmvc

I call Spring controller using org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.

It looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml" })
public class TestController {

    @Mock
    private TestService testService;

    @InjectMocks
    private TestController testController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.setMockMvc(MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(testtController).build());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/trans/").param("name", "grep")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

Everything looks well.  I can pass params too. 
But now I need to send JSON (String) instead of params. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `.content()` instead of `.param()`:

```java
post("/trans/").content("{\"name\": \"grep\"}")
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.content()` instead of `.param()`, and should set contentType

```
post("/trans/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("{\"name\": \"grep\"}")
```